# Select All From Table A and if available from Table B

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i didn't find any solution to my specific problem in this forum.

I have two tables
Table **A** has userData with userId name etc.
Table **B** has the orders with userid productName etc.

I want to SELECT all data from Table A and if the same UserID exists in Table B.

So for example:

```
Table A:
UserId  Name  
1       John
2       Britta
3       Tom

Table B:
UserId  ProductName
1       Apple
1       Banana
```

**I want to fetch it like this - i get all the Data from Table A and also the one for John in Table B.**

```
UserId  Name    ProductName
1       John    Apple
1       John    Banana
2       Britta  
3       Tom
```

For now I have only the query to select, fetch and bind alle data from Table A:

```
   $db_obj = getDbConnection();

$sql = "SELECT id, username, role, email, status, salutation, firstname, lastname, street, pc, fs, country FROM users";
      $stmt = $db_obj->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $role, $email, $status, $salutation, $firstname, $lastname, $street, $pc, $fs, $country);

$data = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    //array_push($data, $row);
    $data[] = ["id"=>$id
        , "username"=>$username
        , "role"=>$role
        , "email"=>$email
        , "status"=>$status
        , "salutation"=>$salutation
        , "firstname"=>$firstname
        , "lastname"=>$lastname
        , "street"=>$street
        , "pc"=>$pc
        , "fs"=>$fs
        , "country"=>$country
    ];
    
}

$stmt->close();
$db_obj->close();
```

Can you help me pls?

Comment: Is this just a simple inner join?

Comment: This would just be a LEFT JOIN on the second table

Comment: Show what you want if a UserId appears more than once in Table B

Comment: i updated my tables so if for example john has two orders it should list join the table again.

Answer (score 2):

thank you Gugu71. I didn't know about "Left Join". I did it with this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT u.id, username, role, email, status, salutation, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.street, u.pc, u.fs, u.country, productname FROM users u LEFT JOIN view_orderdetails v ON u.id = v.id ";
```

Comment: Yep, that's the way to do it. `LEFT JOIN` is short for `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and is quite common. There also exists a `RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN`, but it tends to make queries illegible, and it is recommended not to use it. Then there is the `FULL [OUTER] JOIN`, but MySQL doesn't support it yet. Make it a habit to qualify all columns when working with more than one table (i.e. `u.username` instead of `username`, etc.).